# IE does not see a media query. Chrome and Firefox do

Tags: media-queries

Hope someone can help. Around line 459 in my css http://192.185.137.91/~gothicarch/ihealth/ there is this media query that IE can''t see. I'm completely stumped. Chrome and FF see it just fine. If someone could take a look I would appreciate it.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:902px){
 h2{
 font-size:20px;
 }
 #callouts-wrapper{
 width:100%;
 padding-left:0;
 text-align:center;
 }
 #callouts{
 float:none;
 text-align:center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
 }
```

[image: Firefox and Chrome]
[image: Internet Explorer]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Internet Explorer you're talking about... IE 8 did not support "only screen" in the media query.